# Role of parameters' name in a function execution - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, parsing, parameters

I am trying to figure out how the parameter's name affects the code.

```js
const x = 123
const y = 456

function doStuff (x) {
  x = 'joe'
  let y = 'jane'
  console.log(`x: ${x} - y: ${y}`)
  y = 'Jane!'
}

doStuff(x)
console.log(`x: ${x} - y: ${y}`)
```

The output will be:

[image]

Now if I change the parameter name to "input:

```js
const x = 123
const y = 456

function doStuff (input) {
  x = 'joe'
  let y = 'jane'
  console.log(`x: ${x} - y: ${y}`)
  y = 'Jane!'
}

doStuff(x)
console.log(`x: ${x} - y: ${y}`)
```

I will get an error:

[image]

Is a parameter's name just an identifier for the input to a function?

I'd be thankful for an explanation for this

Comment: @Aks Javoes
I see, thank you. But why do I get an error on the "x" variable? because in both codes "x" is declared as a constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function parameters are names given to the arguments passed in to the function, but they also act as mutable variables within the scope of the function. Within the function's scope, function parameters can 'shadow' variables from an outer scope; that is what happens with `x`:

- In the first example, you have a `const x = ...` declared and defined at the outer scope, but your function has an `x` parameter. When you write `x = 'joe'` in the function body, `x` refers to the *function parameter* `x`; the outer `const x` is hidden (it is 'shadowed').
- In the second example, you have a `const x = ...` declared and defined at the outer scope, but your function no longer has an `x` parameter. When you write `x = 'joe'` in the function body, `x` refers to the *outer variable* `const x`. The error is caused by the outer variable being a constant, to which you cannot assign a value.

When you call `doStuff(x)`, you are passing in the *value* of `x`, which comes from `const x = 123`. That means that in your function body, `x` (in the first example) has the value `123`, but is completely separate from the `const x` in the outer scope. In the second example, `input` has the value `123`, but is still completely separate from the `const x` variable.

Answer (score 0):

A parameter has the same effect as a `var` statement, it creates that name within the scope:

```
const x = 123;

function doStuff() {
  var x;
  x = 'joe';
}

function doStuff(x) {
  x = 'joe';
}
```

In both cases `x` is a variable local to `doStuff` and it shadows the outer `x`. The parameter acts as if a `var x` was declared in the function.

If you change the parameter name to `input`, obviously it now acts like `var input`, *not* shadowing the outer `x` because it's obviously a different name, so `x = 'joe'` tries to assign to the outer `x`, which fails because that's a `const` and cannot be assigned to.